# Powershell and 2 factor authentication in Visual Studio Code

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-code

Is there a add on or plug in that enables 2 factor authentication for Microsoft PowerShell that functions like the Microsoft Exchange Online Powershell Module?

Now that MS 2FA is enabled it stop you running Powershell with out using the Microsoft Exchange Online PowerShell Module.

Answer (score 0):

MFA is setup in Azure AD or O365, not in PS, the you use PS (consolehost, ISE, VSCode) to connect using and MFA enabled account via the defined Exchange module.

[Connect to Exchange Online PowerShell using multi-factor authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/exchange/exchange-online/connect-to-exchange-online-powershell/mfa-connect-to-exchange-online-powershell?view=exchange-ps)

If you want to use multi-factor authentication (MFA) to connect to Exchange Online PowerShell, you can't use the instructions at Connect to Exchange Online PowerShell to use remote PowerShell to connect to Exchange Online.

***MFA requires you to install the Exchange Online Remote PowerShell Module, and use the Connect-EXOPSSession cmdlet to connect.***

1.On your local computer, open the Exchange Online Remote PowerShell Module ( Microsoft Corporation > Microsoft Exchange Online Remote PowerShell Module).
2.The command that you need to run uses the following syntax:

```
Connect-EXOPSSession -UserPrincipalName <UPN> [-ConnectionUri <ConnectionUri> -AzureADAuthorizationEndPointUri <AzureADUri>]
```

[Using PowerShell ISE to connect to Exchange Online when MFA is enabled](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/richardroddy/2018/04/04/using-powershell-ise-to-connect-to-exchange-online-when-mfa-is-enabled)